# Foldr compare acc to empty list

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to write function and i dont know why i cannot make it in that way

```
ssm'  = foldr (\x acc -> if acc == [] then [x]++acc else if (x > (maximum acc)) then [x]++acc else acc) []
```

give me a clue please.

Comment: it does not compile at all on my ghci... i'm trying to rewrite that function ssm xs = foldr ((:) . head) [] (groupBy (>=)  xs)  without using groupby

Comment: If you're using `ghci` are you remembering to use the `let` syntax? `let ssm' = ....`

Comment: i'm loading it from file

Comment: Since monomorphism restriction is rarely useful in GHCi, you can put `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` into your `.ghci` file. Look [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html).

Comment: It would really save time if you would include the error message you get in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've run into the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). You can fix it by adding a type signature.

```
ssm' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
ssm' = ...
```

Answer (score 6):

By the way, your code looks way too complicated. You overuse `if`, and `[x]++acc` is just `x:acc`. Scanning `acc` in every step using `maximum` is wasteful, as its biggest element *must* be its head. Alltogether I'd write:

```
ssm' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
ssm' = foldr go [] where
  go x [] = [x]
  go x ms@(m:_) 
    | x > m = x:ms
    | otherwise = ms
```

If you *really* like one-liners, try

```
import Data.List
ssm' xs = reverse $ map head $ groupBy (>) (reverse xs)
```

Comment: my oneline was easier i posted it in coment under first post without reverse anyway thanks for your solution